# IOException on HTTP post request

Tags: android, accountmanager

I am creating a login form using `Account Manager`account manager and `HTTP` task for webservices. when i enter the username and password it gives me `IOException`, I have added the `INTERNET PERMISSION` and all the account related permission. If anyone knows any github example which uses account manager and webservices please share the url.please help.this is the code
`

```
 public void userSignUp(String name, String email, String pass, String authType, final SignUPHandler handler) {

        HttpPost localHttpPost = new HttpPost(ApiURL.USERSIGNIN);

        JSONObject json_user = new JSONObject();

        try {
            json_user.put("email", email);
            json_user.put("password", pass);

            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json_user.toString());
            localHttpPost.setEntity(se);
            if ((this.currentTask != null) && (this.currentTask.getStatus() != AsyncTask.Status.FINISHED))
                this.currentTask.cancel(true);

            this.currentTask = new HttpTask(ApiURL.HTTP_LOGIN_HOST, new HttpResponseHandler() {
                public void handleException(Exception paramException) {
                    Log.e("Exceptionssssssss:", "" + paramException);
                    handler.handleException(paramException);
                }

                public void handleResponse(JSONObject json)
                        throws IOException {
                    Log.d("response", "" + json);
                    handler.handleResponse(json);
                }
            });
            this.currentTask.execute(new HttpUriRequest[]{localHttpPost});
        } catch (Exception localException) {
            Log.d("Exception ID", "" + localException.getMessage());
        }
    }`
```

Comment: did you debugged using break points ? So that you"ll know at which line you are getting Exception

Comment: It is giving an exception at Log.e("Exceptionsssssss;",+paramException).can you please give any link to example that uses account manager and webservice to login